# Using private image to start kube-proxy

Tags: kubernetes

I need to run kubernetes cluster using private images. I started with config generated by `kubeadm init` (I'm a newbie to kubernetes) and modified `.yaml` files to use my own images. When `kubelet` starts it runs rest of the services.

It works fine but one `kube-proxy` is being run using gcr.io image. There was no `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.yaml` file generated by `kubeadm init` (like it was done for other services) so I created one by myself but it doesn't help (still gcr.io is being run).

From my observation `kube-proxy` is started by `kube-apiserver` (when apiserver is disabled proxy doesn't run) but I couldn't find a way to prevent it.

Is it possible to make `kubelet` run `kube-proxy` from my private image and use it for `kube-apiserver` (recompilation of kubernetes is acceptable)?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I searched config files and haven't found anything related to `gcr.io` and `--cloud-provider` isn't used.

Comment: This is kinda late, but look into `/etc/kubernetes/` on the master.

Comment: @ConnorJC I think it turned out to be hardcoded somewhere in build process of kubernetes. Shame on me I forgot to add answer and now I don't remember what was it.